# trying to publish a VS Code Extension

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I have developed a typescript app and I would like to convert as a vs code extension, in order to publish it at visual studio code marketplace.
I have already tried with [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) but the commands here generate a template from scratch.
Also tried to do that within my project but it outputs this error: [image]
All I want is to convert the actual project I have in a Vs code extension.

Comment: Create an extension project using `yo code` and then cut and paste useful code snippets from your old project to this new one. Don't attempt to "convert" in any other way as you can easily miss something.

Comment: You mean  to create the extension within the project? Does it work like that?

Answer (score 1):

1. open package.json
2. move `vscode` dependency in section `devDependencies`

e.g

```
"devDependencies": {
   //...rest of the dependencies, 
   "vscode": "^1.1.37"
}
```